# htaccess rewrite for codeigniter site

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting, codeigniter-url

I want to rewrite code for codeigniter url rewrite.

I have used following code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /whype
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^admin$ administration
RewriteRule ^video/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ videos/details/$1/$1
```

It is working well for index.php removal.
But it doesn't work for url rewrite

i want `example.com/admin` becomes `example.com/administration`

and

`example.com/video/123/title` becomes `example.com/videos/details/123/title`

Thanks in advance,
w3father

Comment: I'm being annoyed by the fact that you can't use extra info in index in controllers, you have to use a different method -> unwanted stuff in url. So I'm interested what works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

And add your routes to the routes.php inside the application/config folder. See [URI Routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need to do is put your two new rules in front of the existing ones.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /whype

RewriteRule ^admin$ administration
RewriteRule ^video/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ videos/details/$1/$2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```